# React Mix ClassName class and props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React button component to which I'm adding props like color, text etc.

At the same time I'm also using Bootstrap css.

So I have a button:

```
<Button text={sometext} color={success} />
```

Then what I want to do is this in the component:

```
<div className="btn btn-lg btn-{this.props.color}" role="button">{this.props.text}</div>
```

See the className and **{this.props.color}** ... this doesn't work.

How can I do this ... add props inside className?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to interpolate variables:

```
<div className={ `btn btn-lg btn-${this.props.color}` } ...
```

Comment: This would be perfect but I get this error: Syntax error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

Comment: @JakeBrown777 my fault, I forgot curly braces. see the update

Comment: Why `{}` works in JSX to compile javascript and if it's mixed with a string it does not work...

Comment: Note that you’ll need spaces inside the curly braces to avoid the `react/jsx-curly-spacing` error.

Answer (score 1):

Before rendering the view set a class variable

```
const classColor = "btn btn-lg btn-" + this.props.color;
```

Then render:

```
<div className={classColor} role="button">{this.props.text}</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly and keeps the code clean. I like your solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
<div className={['btn btn-lg btn-', this.props.color].join('')}>...
```